# Simple Subquery Statement, receiving an error

Tags: sql, oracle, subquery

We are learning subqueries in Oracle SQL. I'm receiving an error `"SQL command not properly ended"` with an example from my textbook that should work.

I have attempted re-spacing the subquery, but keeping the exact code, this should work

```
SELECT last_name, salary
FROM employees
WHERE salary > 11000
                (SELECT salary
                 FROM employees
                 WHERE last_name='Abel');
```

> ERROR at line 4: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

Comment: Looks like a typo in your textbook.  What is this query trying to do, find the salary larger than 11000 or the salary larger than Abel's?

Comment: This book has some errors in it. My professor wrote  back explaining this. Thank you for your response :D

Comment: Please explain what  the code is supposed to be doing.

Answer (score 2):

There needs to be something between the `11000` and the following subselect. As an example, it might be that the following was intended:

```
SELECT last_name, salary
FROM employees
WHERE salary > 11000 AND
      salary IN (SELECT salary
                 FROM employees
                 WHERE last_name='Abel');
```

Comment: Thanks, got it! 

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
SELECT last_name, salary
FROM employees
WHERE salary > 11000 AND
      last_name = 'Abel';
```

This would return employees named "Abel" whose salary exceeds 11,000.

Comment: The textbook implies the 11000 but writes it in the main query area. Because our books are grayscale I thought it was part of the code.